# Specrun Command Line Filter by name of feature

Tags: specrun

How to run Specrun using a filter of feature's name

Fragment of Default.srprofile:

```
<TestAssemblyPaths>
       <TestAssemblyPath>smth.dll</TestAssemblyPath>
</TestAssemblyPaths>
<Filter></Filter>
<DeploymentTransformation>
```

Cmd:
SpecRun.exe run Default.srprofile /filter:"features:Feature:FeatureName"

Here example from github:

```
  Scenario: Should be able to filter for feature
        Given the filter is configured to 'testpath:Feature:Feature_1'
        When I execute the tests
        Then the execution summary should contain
        | Total | 
        | 3     |
```

https://github.com/mikeborozdin/BDD-with-SpecFlow-and-White/blob/master/packages/SpecRun.0.13.0.72/docs/Filtering/03_TestPathFiltering.feature

Comment: Solved:
SpecRun.exe run Default.srprofile /filter:testpath:Feature:FeatureName

Comment: If you feel the question and answer will be useful to others try and remember there is an 'answer my own question' feature available after a certain time period.

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen Thanks for an advice!
But I do not see this feature, at least for now.

Comment: ahh, maybe it's not available to new users :)